# get item from another sharepoint list to send email in Microsoft Flow

Tags: sharepoint, lookup, power-automate

I have 2 list,

- list 1  "location" contain 2 columns location (type=Single Line of Text) and person (type =person),
- list 2 "Helpdesk" contains 3 columns description, category and Loc

Problem:

When a new item is created on the list - HelpDesk, i want to create a flow where the column "Loc" is looked up in the list "location" and send email to the corresponding value for person.

Answer (score 1):

I could think of two different solutions to this:

1. You could create a linked column in the "HelpDesk" list to the "Location" list, which would automatically pull the information you need over to the "HelpDesk" list from within SharePoint. Thus, your Flow could grab the email data without having to cross reference the lists, because the linked column would make that data accessible from the "HelpDesk" list.
2. If that isn't a solution for you, then you could just cross reference the lists. Assuming the data in the "Loc" column is the same for both lists, and you're just trying to get the email address that corresponds to that "Loc", you could get all the records from the "Location" list. Then filter that query based on the "Loc" value from the "HelpDesk" record. Then take the email data from the single record (assuming there is a single record for each "Loc" in the "Location" list).

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the flow like this:

1.When an item is created or modified in the list "HelpDesk".

2.Get Item- since the column "Loc" is looked up column, you could get the item in the list "location" with the ID "Loc Id".

3.Then send email to the person column.

Comment: Michael, your step #2 is almost exactly what I am trying to do. Can you explain how to do that? I posted a question that is like getting the "Loc" value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61139897/how-to-retrieve-value-in-selected-sharepoint-list-item-column