# How to retrieve value in selected SharePoint list item column

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

In a SharePoint list, I have a column that holds a foreign key ID to another list. For example:

- list **teachers**
- list **classes** with foreign key column **teacherID** to teacher item

I am trying to create a Power Automate flow that starts with a SharePoint "For a selected item" in **classes** and then modifies the referenced **teacher** list item.

1. "For selected item" in **classes**
2. Modify **teachers** item referenced by classes.**teacherID**

All(!) I need to do is get the value of **teacherID**, but that has turned out to be incredibly difficult. How can I do this? I'm new to Power Automate so any suggestions appreciated.

What I've tried:

- Created a second action to email me output from the first action (because I don't know any other way to "debug" or "watch" this). Added many different types of Dynamic content and expressions to the email body. **teacherID** never appears. It is not in the list of Dynamic content fields. I cannot find in expressions tried e.g. `triggerBody`, `trigger`, `output`, `actions('For a selected item')` (which is an error for some unknown reason but I'm not trying to understand why at the moment). In the JSON, all I have been able to retrieve so far is `ID`, `itemURL`, `fileName`, `FileId` (which looks the same as ID).
- My next thought was, okay, maybe "For a selected item" doesn't have access to the other list columns, but maybe "Get item" does. So, I inserted a "Get item" (singular, not "Get item*s*) but this frustratingly did not make any difference.

What I am trying to do should be very simple and straightforward. The documentation is sparse, and it sucks TBH.

Comment: I found a way to do it but won't post it as an answer yet because I'm not sure if it's a good way or not. 1. discovered when data type of teacherID changed from number to "single line of text", it appeared as available dynamic content to be added to email 2. peeked code and saw it references the original name of column!! i.e. body('Get_item')?['temp'] instead of body('Get item')?['teacherID']. 3. in action to update classes item, used body('Get_item')?['temp']. Worked! ('teacherID' does not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lookup column name is **teacherID**, you should use **teacherID Id** in the flow to find the item in **teachers**

You could create the flow like this:

1. "For a selected item" in **classes**
2. "Get item" in **classes**
3. "Update item" in **teachers**

[image]

Comment: The struggle for me was getting that teacherID to show up in the Dynamic content list. When I changed the data type of the column, it started to show up.